# In Employee table how to update Experience column of All Employee based on Date Of joining column

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have an Employee table and I want to update the Experience column of all employees based on their date of joining `DOJ` column.

```
+----+---------+------------+-------------+------------+
| Id |  name   |    DOJ     | Designation | Experience |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  1 | Krishna | 14/01/2012 | Developer   |            |
|  2 | Rahim   | 14/01/2013 | Developer   |            |
|  3 | Ram     | 14/01/2014 | Developer   |            |
|  4 | Shyam   | 14/01/2015 | Developer   |            |
|  5 | Ashok   | 14/01/2016 | Developer   |            |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: How do you want to update `Experience` column?

Comment: Store dates using a date data type.

Answer (score 0):

**Experience** calculated in *years*,

```
UPDATE test SET Experience = floor(datediff(curdate(),DOJ) / 365)
```

**Experience** calculated in *months*,

```
UPDATE test SET Experience = 12 * (YEAR(Curdate()) - YEAR(DOJ)) + (MONTH(curdate()) - MONTH(DOJ))
```